# How are system calls interrupted by signal?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

My understanding is as following :

the blocking syscall would normally place the process in the 'TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE' state so that when a signal is delivered, the kernel places the process into 'TASK_RUNNING' state. And the process will be scheduled to run when the next timer tick happens , so that the syscall is interrupted .

But I did a small test , it failed . I worte a usermode process , which called sleep(). And I changed the process's state into TASK_RUNNING in kernel , but sleep() did not be interrupted at all and the process was still sleeping.

Then I tryed wake_up_process(process) , it failed.

Then I tryed set_tsk_thread_flag(process,TIF_SIGPENDING), it failed.

Then I tryed set_tsk_thread_flag(process,TIF_SIGPENDING) and wake_up_process(process), succeeded !!   sleep() was interrupted and the process started to run .

So it's not that simple. Does anyone know how exactly are system calls interrupted by signal ?

Comment: If you just call `wake_up_process()`, then the process wakes up, checks to see what happens, and discovers that there was no reason to wake, so it goes straight back to sleep.  If you just set the flag without waking the process, then it doesn't wake up so doesn't check the flag.  You need to do both.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`__send_signal`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.10.1/kernel/signal.c#L1046) from `signal.c`. It calls `complete_signal` near the end, which eventually calls this little function:

```
void signal_wake_up_state(struct task_struct *t, unsigned int state)
{
        set_tsk_thread_flag(t, TIF_SIGPENDING);
        /*
         * TASK_WAKEKILL also means wake it up in the stopped/traced/killable
         * case. We don't check t->state here because there is a race with it
         * executing another processor and just now entering stopped state.
         * By using wake_up_state, we ensure the process will wake up and
         * handle its death signal.
         */
        if (!wake_up_state(t, state | TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE))
                kick_process(t);
}
```

And that's how you do it. Note that it is not enough to set the thread flag: you have to use a wakeup function to ensure the process is scheduled.

Comment: ,I  tryed  wake_up_process() without seting the thread flag , it failed too. So I want to  when and how are system calls interrrupted by signal ?

Comment: ...you set the thread flag, then you wake up the process. Miss either of those two steps and it won't work. What's unclear about that?